# Where is the data saved, from the Datatable-items, in ECM eRoom-database?

Tags: sql-server, emc, eroom

I am trying to retrieve data out of the ECM eRoom Database (which isn't documented, as I know of).

I have an eRoom with an custom *"Database"*, some Fields.
[image: eroom database icon]

When I query the objects table I find the *"Database"* row
`select * from[dbo].[Objects] where internalId = 1234567`

[image: screenshot database table result]

and the Rows for the entries
`select top 10 * from[dbo].[Objects] where parentInternalId = 1234567`

[image: screenshot database table result]

but I don't find any field with the values of the entries, only an Column with `NonSearchableProperties.`, that is only full with Hex Data.

[image: screenshot database table result]

My Question(s),

- how could i retrieve the values?
- Is it possible to retrieve them with mere SQL?
- What is the simplest way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## This is not the silver bullet, but it is okay for my usecase

After long goolging and alot of test scripts, i found some answers, but probably due to the fact the the system is soon end-of-life and that the documentation is not easy to read, here are my finding.

***Is it possible to retrieve them with mere SQL?***
As far as I could find out, **no!** *(please correct me If I'm wrong)*

***how could i retrieve the values?***
With the eRoom API(on the Server there are some Sample programms to query the data/objects **<installation-path>\eRoom Server\Toolkit\Samples,** with c++, vb, vbscript, ... all a bit to much overhead), or  with the eRoom XML Query Language(**exql**) over soap calls.

***What is the simplest way?***
After alot of tests, searching in forums and many tests with soap ui. I found out that queries with **exql** seem to be the simplest way to retrieve Data, **if** you understand the structure.
Here some ressource that were helpful:

- (very) Basic info of exql from the manufacturer https://eroom.asce.org/eRoomHelp/en/XML_Help/Introduction.htm
  *(**disclaimer:** I didn't find it helpful, but it shows at least some basics)*
- short 9 page Developer guide https://developer-content.emc.com/developer/downloads/eRoomXMLCapabilitiesUseCaseProgramDashboard.pdf (the last example on page 8, helped me understand how to setup the query, with alot of fantasy)

But for this to work, don't forget, to activate ***Allow XML queries and commands from external applications*** in the Site Settings

[image: screenshot Sitesettings]

> ### TIP 1:
>
> you always can go go deeper you just need to know the right xml-element under. `<Database>`, `<Cells>` and `<DBCell>` can help you go deeper
>
> ### TIP 2:
>
> don't query to much data since this query likely run into timeouts

**Update 1:**
Just to save time for anyone who is looking, this "query" returns all rows (properties) for a Database(s) created in an eRoom Root.

*(don't forget to set **facility** and **room** in the Url ex. [http://server/eroomxml/facilities/**TEST**/Rooms/**TestRoom**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33434222/where-is-the-data-saved-from-the-datatable-items-in-ecm-eroom-database),  although it could be set in the query)*

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:er="http://www.eroom.com/eRoomXML/2003/700">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <er:ExecuteXMLCommand>
         <er:eRoomXML>
            <er:command er:select="HomePage/Items">
                <er:getproperties>
                    <er:Item>
                        <Database>
                            <Rows>
                                <Item>
                                    <Cells>
                                        <DBCell>
                                            <Content>
                                            </Content>
                                        </DBCell>
                                    </Cells>
                                </Item>
                            </Rows>
                        </Database>
                   </er:Item>
                </er:getproperties>
             </er:command>
         </er:eRoomXML>
      </er:ExecuteXMLCommand>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```